# Invert color in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs6

I would like to invert the color of this flame in Illustrator. Is there an easy way to do it?

In Photoshop it's simple (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) but that doesn't work in Illustrator.

[image: Flame]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Menu Edit** > **Edit Colors** > **Invert Colors**

[image: invert colors]

Comment: wow simple! tks a lot